# Volume command in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, command, volume

Ive made the command and it works but it doesn't change the volume of the bot it keeps saying "Volume only can be set in a range of **`1`** - **`100`**"
but i typed "volume 1 and it didnt work

Command -

```
 } else if (message.content.startsWith('"volume')) {
        const args = message.content
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send("I'm sorry, but you need to be in a voice channel to set a volume!");
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send("There is nothing playing");
        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send(`The current volume is: **\`${!serverQueue.volume}%\`**`);
        if (isNaN(args[1]) || args[1] > 100) return message.channel.send("Volume only can be set in a range of **\`1\`** - **\`100\`**");
        serverQueue.volume = args[1];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume(args[1] / 100);
        return message.channel.send(`I set the volume to: **\`${args[1]}%\`**`);
        return;
```

Functions -

```
 const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
        .play(ytdl(song.url))
        .on("finish", () => {
            if (!serverQueue.loop) serverQueue.songs.shift()
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on("error", error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Started playing: **${song.title}**`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it because you are missing `.split()` when you are assigning to `args`?

```js
const args = message.content.split(" ");
```

It will break the message content by spaces into an array. Your commands would look like this `"volume 5`.